# switch tabs in playwright test

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm trying to switch between tabs using playwright tests
but it's not taking control of windows element.
Do we have any method similar to selenium driver.switchto().window() in playwright?

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--start-maximized'] });
    const context = await browser.newContext({ viewport: null });
    context.on("page", async newPage => {
        console.log("***newPage***", await newPage.title())
    })
    const page = await context.newPage()
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()

    // dummy url
    await page.goto('https://www.myapp.com/')
    await navigationPromise

    // User login
    await page.waitForSelector('#username-in')
    await page.fill('#username-in', 'username')
    await page.fill('#password-in', 'password')
    await page.click('//button[contains(text(),"Sign In")]')
    await navigationPromise

    // User lands in application home page and clicks on link in dashboard 
    // link will open another application in new tab 
    await page.click('(//span[text()="launch-app-from-dashboard"])[2]')

    await navigationPromise
    await page.context()
    // Waiting for element to appear in new tab and click on ok button
    await page.waitForTimeout(6000)
    await page.waitForSelector('//bdi[text()="OK"]')
    await page.click('//bdi[text()="OK"]')

})()
```

Comment: I think my answer here can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277178/how-to-open-the-new-tab-using-playwright-ex-click-the-button-to-open-the-new-s/64279379#64279379

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `"launch-app-from-dashboard"` is creating a new page tag, you can use the following pattern to run the subsequent lines of code on the new page. See [multi-page scenarios doc](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.5.0&path=docs%2Fmulti-pages.md&q=) for more examples.

```js
// Get page after a specific action (e.g. clicking a link)
const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
  context.waitForEvent('page'),
  page.click('a[target="_blank"]') // Opens a new tab
])
await newPage.waitForLoadState();
console.log(await newPage.title());
```

Since you run headless, it might also be useful to switch the visible tab in the browser with `page.bringToFront` ([docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/multi-pages#handling-new-pages)).

Comment: a question here: will it just click the very first a[target="_blank"] ? Or, how would this work on a second link  since there would more than one of the 'a[target="_blank"]' ??

Comment: the link above is not working (the multi page docs ) - please fix

Comment: @AlexD its an example we can put the appropriate locator which should bring only one element

Answer (score 0):

```
it('Open a new tab and check the title', async function () {
  await page.click(button, { button: "middle" }); //to open an another tab
  await page.waitForTimeout(); // wait for page loading 
  let pages = await context.pages();
  expect(await pages[1].title()).equal('Title'); /to compare the title of the second page
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The browserContext?.pages() is an array that contains the tabs opened by your application, from there you can use a temporal page to make a switch, once completed your validations you can switch back.

```
playwright.pageMain: Page = await playwright.Context.newPage();
playwright.pageTemp: Page; 

// Save your current page to Temp 
playwright.pageTemp = playwright.pageMain;

// Make the new tab launched your main page
playwright.pageMain = playwright.browserContext?.pages()[1];
expect(await playwright.pageMain.title()).toBe('Tab Title');
```

Comment: what's `playwright` here? did you import the whole module and are using it as a variable in this local scope? please give us some context :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you only created one page (via browser context), but for some reason, new pages/tabs open.
You can have a list of all the pages by : `context.pages`,
Now each element of that list represents a **<class 'playwright.async_api._generated.Page'>** object.
So, now you can assign each page to any variable and access it. (For eg. `page2 = context.pages[1]`)